# How do I remove custom props from a Rebass element extended with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I want to create a reusable "IconButton" using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) to extend a [Rebass Button](http://jxnblk.com/rebass/components/Button), but I'm getting this warning:

`Unknown props 'small, 'overlay' on <button> tag. Remove these props from the element`

How do I remove these props from the element?

```
export default ({
  ...props,
  type,
  action,
  top,
  small,
  overlay
}) =>
  <IconButton
    onClick={() => action()}
    px={3}
    mt={top && 2}
    small={small}
    overlay={overlay}>
    {Icons[type]()}
  </IconButton>;

const IconButton = styled(Button)`
  background: ${({ overlay }) => (overlay ? "white" : "transparent")};
  svg {
    height: ${props =>
      props.small ? props.theme.fontSizes[4] : props.theme.fontSizes[5]}px;
    width: ${props => props.theme.fontSizes[5]}px;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Did you take a look at these links. `https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/305`
`https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/439`

Comment: Thank you @panther...

I found [a solution](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/439#issuecomment-307335814) in the second link.